# zend2 email validation

Tags: zend-form, zend-framework2

I have FROM with validators. I use "pl_PL" as locale. In this form 
validators like 'StringLength', 'EmailAddress'.

When I use 'Int' I have "Fatal error: Class 'Locale' not found in C:\ccc\bbbbbb\library\Zend\I18n\Validator\Int.php on line 63" info.

Answer (score 0):

you need to install Intl extension, read this : http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php